# Strange SELECT behavior

Tags: string, postgresql

I have this strange problem. i have a table with 10 columns of type character varying.

I need to have a function that searches all records and returns the id of the record which has all strings. Lets say records:

```
1. a,b,c,d,e
2. a,k,l,h
3. f,t,r,e,w,q
```

if i call this function func(a,d) it should return 1, if i call func(e,w,q) its should return 3.

The function is

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func(ma1 character varying,ma2 character varying,ma3 character varying,ma4 character varying)
DECLARE name numeric; 
BEGIN
 SELECT Id INTO name from Table WHERE
  ma1 IN (col1,col2,col3,col4) AND
  ma2 IN (col1,col2,col3,col4) AND
  ma3 IN (col1,col2,col3,col4) AND
  ma4 IN (col1,col2,col3,col4);
RETURN name;
END;
```

It's working 90% of the time, the weird problem is that some rows are not found.

Its not uppercase or lowercase problem.

What can be wrong, its version 9.1 on 64 bit win 7. I feel its like encoding or string problem but i can't see where and what.

//Ok i found the problem, it has to do with all column, if  all 24 columns are filled in then its not working ?? but why ? are there limitations becouse there are 24 columns that i must compare with//

Can someone help me plz.

thanks.

Comment: Can you set up an example on [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) that shows the error?

Comment: Hi Igor,  there are no errors, its just returning null selected.

Comment: If you want better help figuring out the problem, you should post some sample passing and failing rows as an `insert` statements here or in SQLFiddle. Also post your full query and the table definition as a `create table` statement.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is (probably) that some of your columns have nulls.

In SQL, any equality comparison with a null is always false. This extends to the list of values used with the `IN (...)` condition.
If any of the values in the list are null, the comparison will be false, even if the value being sought is in the list.

The work-around is to make sure no values are null. which unfortunately results in a verbose solution:

```
WHERE ma1 IN (COALESCE(col1, ''), COALESCE(col2, ''), ...)
```

Comment: Thank you Bohemian, but there are no null values, if its ampty then its ''. And its working for the most of the rows, but somehow only for some rows its not working. Its so iretating, its like somerhing wrong with this rows and not the values. Becose lets say if value of ather row like '100' working, i am changing a value to 100 on this rows, but still its not working.

Comment: Are there indexes on the columns? If so, they could be corrupted, so try dropping them and recreating them. Also, try executing `analyze mytable`

Comment: No index, analyze retourned no problems.

Comment: Some of the values that not working are '40 CM' or '120 CM', can be something wrong with CM ?

Comment: Ok i found it, it has to do with the last column, if it is filled in then its not working ?? but why ?

Comment: What's the datatype of the column? Also, is it only values with spaces? If so, the "space" may not be a space, it may be a tab or some other character. Try selecting the ascii code of the character by using `select ascii(substr(col, 3, 1))` to display the 3rd char of `"40 CM"`

Comment: datatype is char vary, the space is space no tab or something else. I have foud the error but not he reason, it is if all the columns are fuilled in then its not working, so i have inserted 1 more colum, and its working. Rows that gave no result ware rows that all columns have value. I hade 24 columns if all of them had value then my query returned null, if i delete the last column then its works, so becose i needed all 24 columns i have added 1 more column, so now i have 25 columns. if i fill in all 25 columns its stil not working ? so when all columns are filled in its, i don't know why.

Comment: Create your schema and the offending data on [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) and post your link in the question

Answer (score 0):

I suspect Bohemian is correct that the problem is related to nulls in your IN clauses.  An alternative approach is to use Postgres's [array contained in operator](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/functions-array.html) to perform your test.

```
where ARRAY[ma1,ma2,ma3,ma4] <@ ARRAY[col1,col2,...,colN]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, there are no null values in de table. I have tried your solution and i am getting this error ERROR:  operator does not exist: text[] <@ character varying[]

Comment: Cast the maX values to `character varying` or cast the col values to `text`. eg: `ARRAY[col1::text,...,colN::text]` to resolve the missing operator error.